# Firebird domain as Rails type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, firebird

I am working on a patch for a firebird rails adapter. My goal is to make it possible to define a column as the type boolean if the domain of the column has a defined name.

I found the `SqlTypeMetadata` class which I am using to create `FirebirdColumns` in the method `fetch_type_metadata` in the module `SchemaStatements`.

But it seems that this is used only after the data is fetched so it doesn't use the defined true/false values in the query. So, right now, I am looking for a way to tell ActiveRecord the type of a column on an adapter basis. I read the files schema_definitions and schema_statements several times in case I am missing something but I couldn't find a method there... .

Where is a method that I can overwrite to make the typecasting correct?

Comment: Firebird 3 has native boolean type. Firebird 2 soon to be deprecated. Is a patch to simulate boolean really needed?

Comment: `But it seems that this is used only after the data is fetched` I do not know about Ruby, but the general SQL execution of query is three-staged: 1) creating a source text of query, 2) "query preparation" - that is passing the sources to server to compile it into its internal executive language, 3) query execution (fetching data by running the compiled "prepared" query). The data types are returned by Firebird after "preparation" phase and before "fetching" phase. OTOH that data can be `SQL DOMAIN` - that is an explicitly created named data type, declared outside of the column itself

Comment: Example from official docs: `CREATE DOMAIN D_BOOLEAN AS
CHAR(3) CHECK (VALUE IN ('Yes', 'No'));` and then `CREATE TABLE ( X D_BOOLEAN )`

Comment: @Arioch'The Although we upgraded to Firebird 3 we still have many columns that are using a domain for boolean. So, I will need it for sure

Comment: The problem I have is that ActiveRecord is not recognizing the colum - in our case a char with limit 1 and domain boolean - as a boolean but as a string. Therefore the type casting is wrong and the genereated sql is not working.
This is the reason why I am searching for a method to tell the adapter that the column is of a different type.

Comment: You would have to find the place where it does type detection, it is should be somewhere after calling `dsql_prepare` Firebird functions family. Unless AR is so basic a library that it only calls `dsql_execute_immediate`, then preparation occurs inside Firebird engine, opaquely

Answer (score 1):

Firebird doesn't communicate information about the domain of a column in the bind information of a prepared query. It only communicates the basic underlying datatype information. So if you have defined a domain `X` with underlying type `CHAR(1)`, then Firebird will communicate it as a `CHAR(1)`, not as `X`.

There is no option to obtain the domain, except by querying the metadata tables for additional information. So, what you want to achieve is either not possible, or at least it will be complicated.

Comment: I managed to do this in a configuration for my Rails adapter. It now knows too when a field is boolean and how to query the database with the right char/int

Comment: @Shimu Good to hear. Consider posting an answer with the changes you made to get it to work. It might be useful for others as well.